# Whats going with the question count?

Tags: bug

I just noticed over the past months a lot of not so interesting questions hit the "Famous Question" 10.000 View count: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/famous-question

Which is a bit strange:

[Expandable lists that expand and collapse with one click](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/106094/expandable-lists-that-expand-and-collapse-with-one-click)

Got 10055 Views in 1.5 years and has **only 1 Upvote**

Edit: here is an overview with advanced search: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=views%3a10000%20is%3aquestion

Comment: It sure is strange, and we have another meta question open related to this, but it seems to not be quite the same issue: http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/a-lot-of-views-in-a-very-short-time